# How to maintain session for a user until user is logged-in in spring mvc

Tags: spring, session

I'm creating a project in spring mvc, hibernate. I'm stuck at maintaining sessions after a user is logged in. I want to maintain the session until the user is logged in. 
Thanks.

Comment: Create a session object and store whatever you need in it,what do you want to store in session, what have you tried, what are you asking for....maintain what session till user logs in

Comment: you can also use spring session which will take care of all the hard parts .https://projects.spring.io/spring-session/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the controller to log in your user you could create and store your session there...

```
    public ModelAndView yourMethod(HttpSession session){

    session.setAttribute("user", 1); 
    return new ModelAndView("home");

}
```

If you want to retrieve it you can do it like this

```
Long userId = (Long) session.getAttribute("user");
```

Spring will maintain the session for you,

Comment: So, is this session available for as many requests as i want.

Comment: It depends on how long you specify the timeout of your session in your configuration, if you set the time to zero it will stay alive unless the session is invalidated explicitly.....<session-config>
    <session-timeout>0</session-timeout>
</session-config>...... you can find this in web.xml

Comment: Thanks guys. for your support. I did it using HttpSession.

Comment: if you have found a solution please accept answer of question, or show other the solution you used to help the community